# can i set "redirect url" dynamically?

Tags: box-api

I have two problems -

1) I need to set the redirect url depending on a server i work on, which means that i need to have the ability to change the redirect url dynamically, 
is there a way to set the redirect url using the API, and not through the web "www.box.com/developers/..." ?

2) I ran into a weird issue today, my app opens the box.net "login window" which redirects to the specified url when the user logs in, it worked fine until today! but for now the "login window" does nothing when the user logs in, it does not responds.
is there something that was changed?

Answer (score 1):

1) yes you can. In the box applications console, leave the redirect url empty for yor app. Then all is needed is to provide a redirect url at runtime, when you make the authentication (this is something you are probably already doing).

2) I cannot reproduce the issue at this time